# Map() function only return last value?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

This is data I wanna get :

```
    "buttons":[
           {
              "name":"Screen1",
              "display":"Screen1",
              "command":"Screen1"
           },
           {
              "name":"Screen2",
              "display":"Screen2",
              "command":"Screen2"
           },
           {
              "name":"Screen3",
              "display":"Screen3",
              "command":"Screen3"
           }
        ]
     },
```

My code to get data buttons :

```
let btnConmand = '';
  let btnName = '';
  let btntest = data.map(ele => {
    if(ele.id == '0100') {
      ele.component[0].buttons.map(btns => {
        btnName = btns.name;
      });
    }
    return btnName ;

  }).join('');
 console.log(btntest)
```

When I write `console.log(btntest)`, it only return last value? How do I get all the values?

Comment: Don't use map like a forEach. Plus you're changing the value of `btnName` so that it will only contain the last value.

Comment: What's `data` contain?

Comment: You are setting value in `btnName` and returning it in all iteration. Instead return `btn.name`

Comment: because it's finishing iterating and returns the last value,(first iterate: btnName = Screen1, second iterate: btnName = Screen2 and so on)

Comment: thanks, how do i get all the values @KonstantinKim?

Comment: A snippet of the source data would really help.

Comment: @Ben i'm testing get data, that all i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want some thing like this.

1) When you use `map` always return the updated value in map function

```
let btntest = data
  .flatMap(ele => {
    let btns = [];
    if (ele.id == "0100") {
      btns = ele.component[0].buttons.map(btns => btns.name);
    }
    return btns;
  })
  .join("");
console.log(btntest);
```

Comment: Hope this helps. If not, please update the question with `data` and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an array

> btntest

as an array. what you currently doing will return the last value as of btntest dataType.